# Excluir linhas da tabela

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um `table` com uma lista de devedores cadastrados 
quero exclui-lo caso ele pague.
Com uma base consegui criar a função e tudo, mas quando atualizo a página, ele volta.

```html
<!-- FAZ A FUNÇÃO DE SALVAR OS DADOS -->
<?php
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');

 setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');

 date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$produto = $_POST['produto'];
$banco = "nova.txt";
if($_POST['acao'] == "CADASTRAR")
{
if(empty($nome)){echo"<script>window.location='cadastro.php';alert('Nome em branco!');</script>";}
elseif(empty($produto)){echo"<script>window.location='cadastro.php';alert('Selecione a venda!');</script>";}
else
{
$data = strftime('%A, %d de %B de %Y', strtotime('today'));
$arquivo = fopen("$banco","r");
$while = fread($arquivo,filesize($banco));
fclose($arquivo);
$abrir = fopen("$banco","w");
if($while == "0"){$salvar ="<table class='lista-clientes' width='100%'>       
<tbody>     
<tr>
<td align='center'></td>
<td> 
    <select class='select_styled'>
       <option value=''>$nome</option>
        <option value=''> Produto: $produto</option>
        <option value=''>Compra dia, $data</option>
</select
 </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
";}
else{$salvar ="<table class='lista-clientes' width='100%'>       
<tbody>     
<tr>
<td align='center'></td>
<td> 
    <select class='select_styled'>
       <option value=''>$nome</option>
        <option value=''> Produto: $produto</option>
        <option value=''>Compra dia, $data</option>
</select>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
$while";}

fwrite($abrir,"$salvar");

fclose($abrir);

echo"<script>window.location='cadastro.php';alert('Cadastrado com Sucesso!');</script>";

}}
?>

<!-- FAZ A FUNÇÃO DE ABRIR OS DADOS-->

<?php

$arquivo = fopen($banco,"r");

$while = fread($arquivo,filesize($banco));

if($while == "0"){echo"<br><br><br><br><center><font face=verdana size=1>Nenhum recado inserido!</font></center><br><br><br><br>";}else{echo"<font face=verdana size=1>$while</font>";}

fclose($arquivo);?>
```

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function($) {

  RemoveTableRow = function(handler) {
    var tr = $(handler).closest('table');

    tr.fadeOut(400, function(){ 
      tr.remove(); 
    }); 

    return false;
  };
})(jQuery);

</script>
```

```html
<!-- faz a funçao de salvar os dados -->
<?php



 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');

 setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');

 date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$produto = $_POST['produto'];
$banco = "nova.txt";
if($_POST['acao'] == "CADASTRAR")
{
if(empty($nome)){echo"<script>window.location='cadastro.php';alert('Nome em branco!');</script>";}
elseif(empty($produto)){echo"<script>window.location='cadastro.php';alert('Selecione a venda!');</script>";}
else
{
$data = strftime('%A, %d de %B de %Y', strtotime('today'));
$arquivo = fopen("$banco","r");
$while = fread($arquivo,filesize($banco));
fclose($arquivo);
$abrir = fopen("$banco","w");
if($while == "0"){$salvar ="<table class='lista-clientes' width='100%'>       
<tbody>     
<tr>
<td align='center'></td>
<td> 
    <select class='select_styled'>
       <option value=''>$nome</option>
        <option value=''> Produto: $produto</option>
        <option value=''>Compra dia, $data</option>
</select
 </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
";}
else{$salvar ="<table class='lista-clientes' width='100%'>       
<tbody>     
<tr>
<td align='center'></td>
<td> 
    <select class='select_styled'>
       <option value=''>$nome</option>
        <option value=''> Produto: $produto</option>
        <option value=''>Compra dia, $data</option>
</select>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
$while";}

fwrite($abrir,"$salvar");

fclose($abrir);

echo"<script>window.location='cadastro.php';alert('Cadastrado com Sucesso!');</script>";

}}

?>


<!-- faz a função de abrir os dados -->
<?php

$arquivo = fopen($banco,"r");

$while = fread($arquivo,filesize($banco));

if($while == "0"){echo"<br><br><br><br><center><font face=verdana size=1>Nenhum recado inserido!</font></center><br><br><br><br>";}else{echo"<font face=verdana size=1>$while</font>";}

fclose($arquivo);?>
```

Quero excluir permanente ou não há maneira por JQuery?

Comment: Tens de apagar no servidor... não chega apagar no browser. De onde vêm essa lista de devedores?

Comment: Como é simples a dinamica nesse eu salvo apenas num arquivo de texto e chamo ele no site que amostra essa lista.

Comment: Mas mesmo esse arquivo de texto está no servidor certo? pois não dá para gravar ficheiros com o browser.

Comment: sim, sim só que ele salva todos os cadastros no mesmo arquivo.

Comment: Podes mostrar o código que usas quando gravas?

Comment: tem outra forma pra eu poder colocar o código aqui no site mas especificado?

Comment: Edita a pergunta que fica melhor ;)

Comment: Ainda não sei perguntar direito aqui, mas coloquei toda a dinamica usada para salvar os dados e mostrar.

Comment: em execução  apenas a que mostra.   http://quetalumapizza.esy.es/lista_devedores.php